# Running ethereumjs/testrpc from a Docker container

Tags: testnets, nodejs, docker

I'm taking a stab at creating a set-up where I have a Docker container from which I run ethereumjs/testrpc (an Ethereum testing environment) and another Docker container running an Express app. I then wanted to be able to connect the two and, let's say, show account balances in my Express app.

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
# RUN npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc --> tested adding this line
# did not work either

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and docker-compose looks as follows

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links: 
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  ethereum:
    image: ethereumjs/testrpc:latest
```

The error output I get looks like

```
web_1       | module.js:471
web_1       |     throw err;
web_1       |     ^
web_1       | 
web_1       | Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-testrpc'
web_1       |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
web_1       |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
web_1       |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
web_1       |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
web_1       |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:7:15)
web_1       |     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
web_1       |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
web_1       |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
web_1       |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
web_1       |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Lastly, the beginning of my `app.js` is

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var TestRPC = require("ethereumjs-testrpc"); // these two lines are throwing
web3.setProvider(TestRPC.provider()); // the errors
```

I'm not understanding how to fix this and have tried different things, none of which seem to work. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `ethereumjs-testrpc` in the dependencies section of your `package.json`? e.g:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^4.0.1"
}
```

If not, it could lead to the error you are getting.

Running `npm install ethereumjs-testrpc --save` will automatically add this to your `package.json`. Note, this is a one time command and doesn't need to be part of the `Dockerfile`. It just updates your package.json using the current latest version.

Also, if you removed the `-g` from

```
# RUN npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc --> tested adding this line
```

... that would probably also work - but having it in your `package.json` removes the need to do this because it will get installed in the command on the previous line:

```
RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is that the 'ethereumjs-testrpc' package is not installed in your Express app container.
You can try adding it to your package.json dependencies and then running npm install again in your Dockerfile, like so:

## Install app dependencies

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install ethereumjs-testrpc
RUN npm install

Also, you can try adding the ethereumjs-testrpc package globally in your Dockerfile, like so:

RUN npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc

Additionally, if you're still having issues, you can check that the package is properly installed in your container by running the following command in your container:

npm list -g ethereumjs-testrpc

It should show the package and its version number